# snprintf doesn't work with double. Getting '?'

Tags: c, string, double

Im looking for way to display double value as string in c. But using snprintf im getting questionmarks instead of value. My code:

```
char temp[50];
double c = 19.15928891;

snprintf(temp, 8,"%lf", c);
putstring(-2, temp); //send characters to rs232 (here getting only '?')
```

Can someone show me another way to display double as string?

Edited, hope now question is ok :)

Comment: "Display double as string without c functions" But you **are** using `snprintf`. What do you actually want? Use a standard library function or not?

Comment: If there is way to display that double as string without snprintf i would love to use that way...

Actually Im trying to use that function but don't want to work...

Comment: @Sahee Do you define `c` anywhere else?

Comment: Of corse there is! How do you think `snprintf` does? By magical intervention? But this is no coding or tutorial service. Show your code, if you have a **specific** problem.

Comment: cad, sadly no. :(
Olaf, I know but why sprintf don't want to work. I have no idea how i can write that...

Comment: AHEM everyone.... note well below:  'putstring is method to send string to rs232' !!

Comment: @MartinJames, now look at my question, just edited EVERYTHING.

Comment: @Sahee Still incomplete. In particular, it doesn't show how you're checking the result.

Comment: @melpomene, I can display String char via LCD display or via rs232

Comment: @user3121023 `atmel studio 6.1.2562`

Comment: @Sahee maybe printing doubles is not implemented on your platform. Did you try with float instead of double ??

Comment: On an embedded system, using the `printf` or `scanf` family is discouraged anyway, because they bloat your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: How do you pass a `float` as a variadic function argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%f` instead of `%lf`. Depending on how old your library is, `%lf` is either the same as `%f` or an error (so just use `%f` in the first place).

Also note that `19.159289` (the result of that `printf`) requires 10 bytes to store, not 8.

Comment: Version: `stdio.h 2135 2010-06-08`, %f doesn't work to. Changed 8 to 10, still questionmark

Comment: The `l` ("ell") modifier is part of C99. It may not be present in libraries not supporting that version of the standard. Anyway, an earlier edit used `%f`.

Comment: @Olaf, Ok Thanks. So is there any other way to print that double?

Comment: @Sahee: Sure. `%f` for all C90-C11 compliant C libraries. Problem might be you do not have a compliant library.

Comment: More likely you forgot to link the math library with `-lm`